Eclipse replacing http with https and failing to find Pydev
Installed Eclipse Version: 2024-03 (4.31.0) on Windows 11 WSL2 (Ubuntu22)
It's running fine, excpet when I try to install Pydev from http://pydev.org/updates it appears to be replacing the http with https and then failing to find the address.
I've confirmed the address (using http) is correct. But the error keeps saying https



The PyDev update site URL is https://www.pydev.org/updates/. See https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pydev-python-ide-eclipse

Since 2023-06 Eclipse forces https for security - https://eclipse.dev/eclipse/news/4.28/platform.php#force-https
